# hover not working properly with opacity

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

HTML

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="img/thumnail1.jpg" class="thumbnail">
            <div class="thumbnail-area fa fa-search-plus"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail:hover{
    background-color: #6bb533;
    border: 1px solid #6bb533;
}
.thumbnail:hover .thumbnail-area{
    opacity:1;
}
.thumbnail-area{
    background: #6bb533;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: -1px;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity:0;
}
```

I need to make the opacity of `.thumbnail-area` to be `1` when hovering the `.thumbnail`. But it seems not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.thumbnail-area` is not nested under `.thumbnail`, it's adjacent to that, so you will need

```
.thumbnail:hover + .thumbnail-area{
    opacity:1;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3V29/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3V29/1/) *(Just bounded the `absolute` positioned element using `position: relative;` container)*

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3V29/2/) *(Added an image for a real preview)*

---

Also, if you see in the last demo, i.e Demo 3, `opacity` isn't comfortable, you can use `display: none;` and on `:hover` make it `display: block;` as anyways you are not fading
the element, or transitioning, so you won't need `opacity`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this before but didn't worked. But now it seems working well! Who knows why! :) Anyway thanks a lot